# how to change default dependency from maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am using maven-dependency-plugin in my project which has dependency on struts 1.3.8. My company does not allow struts 1.3.8 to be downloaded due to some security concern. How can I change it to different version.

Comment: First why do you use maven-dependency-plugin in Maven project? For what purpose?

Comment: I am unpacking native dependencies which are coming as zip to root folder

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html and specially at the following section:

```
...
    <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>[ groupId ]</groupId>
                  <artifactId>[ artifactId ]</artifactId>
                  <version>[ version ]</version>
                  <type>[ packaging ]</type>
                  <classifier> [classifier - optional] </classifier>
                  <overWrite>[ true or false ]</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>[ output directory ]</outputDirectory>
                  <destFileName>[ filename ]</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
              <!-- other configurations here -->
    </configuration>
...
```

in [ version ] you should be able to set your apropriate version.
You also need to set the fields [ groupId ], [ artifactId ], and so on too, but i assume that you already have done that and only need the [ version ] element or am i wrong?
But if i may ask: Why do you need the Plugin? Does a dependency like:

```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>your.atrifact.group.id</groupId>
           <artifactId>artifactID</artifactId>
           <version>your_version</version>
       </dependency>
```

not do the trick for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can always define a dependency to the plugin:

- Change the groupId/artifactId of struts for whatever it is.
- Change the version of struts for the good one. I used a version range which should ignore version 1.3.8.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>...</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>struts</groupId> 
      <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
      <version>[1.3,1.3.8)</version>
    <dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```